# Can we define a higher-kinded type-level identity function in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, types, higher-kinded-types

In Scala we can define the type-level identity function for lower-kinded types like so,

```
type Id[A] = A
```

Can we also define something similar for higher-kinded types? Ie. can we fill in the blanks in,

```
type HKId[A[...]] = ...
```

so that something similar to HKId[List] gets us back to the List type constructor?

Binding of free names in things like,

```
type Foo[X] = List[X]
val l : Foo[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

Might lead us to expect that a higher-kinded type-level identity would look like,

```
type HKId[A[X]] = A[X]
```

but scalac complains that type X is not found on the RHS.

Is there some clever encoding that will do the trick? Or is it just not possible right now?

Comment: Can't test, but what abot `HKId[A[_]] = A`

Comment: +1 for making my head explode

Comment: @Dario No ... "error: type A takes type parameters" on the RHS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems a bit unfair to snatch the correct answer away from @retronym, but it looks like we can get a little closer to the kind of solution I was after,

```
scala> type HKId[A[_]] = { type λ[X] = A[X] }
defined type alias HKId

scala> def foo[C[_]] : C[Int] = null.asInstanceOf
foo: [C[_]]=> C[Int]

scala> foo[List]
res0: List[Int] = null

scala> foo[HKId[List]#λ]
res1: List[Int] = null
```

I'm not sure why this seems obvious now but wasn't obvious a year ago ... maybe because we've all got a lot more used to seeing type lambdas since then.

Comment: Yes, it does seem obvious once you see it!

Answer (score 14):

`X` in `type HKId[A[X]] = ...` is a higher order type parameter. It is scoped to the type parameter clause, usually referenced in a type constraint. See §4.4 of the spec:

> The above scoping restrictions are
>   generalized to the case of nested type
>   parameter clauses, which declare
>   higher-order type parameters.
>   Higher-order type parameters (the type
>   parameters of a type parameter t ) are
>   only visible in their immediately
>   surrounding parameter clause (possibly
>   including clauses at a deeper nesting
>   level) and in the bounds of t .
>   Therefore, their names must only be
>   pairwise different from the names of
>   other visible parameters. Since the
>   names of higher-order type parameters
>   are thus often irrelevant, they may be
>   denoted with a ‘_’, which is nowhere
>   visible.

A while back, we discussed the possibility of adding a literal syntax for type functions, e.g. `[A] Either[Int, A]`. This would be really useful in Scalaz. In the meantime, we use the trick from Alexey's answer, expressed in the [PartialApplyXofY traits](http://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/PartialApplys.scala). Inference would be even better, but that's much trickier, despite the [innocuous entry in Trac](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/2712)!)

Anyway, during that thread, [Adriaan mentioned](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.scala.internals/3051/match=types+notation+compostion):

> It obviously won't be trivial to
>   implement everything that logically
>   follows from having anonymous type
>   functions, as we currently don't have
>   the necessary infrastructure to allow
>   people to write higher-kinded type
>   aliases, for example:
>
> type MyTypeFun = [X, Y] Pair[Y, X] //
>   desirable, but hard to support with
>   the current implementation (we look at
>   the type params of a symbol to infer
>   its kind)

**UPDATE**

Turns out you can get pretty close already:

```
def hk[_[_]] = (); 
hk[({type A[X] = X})#A]
```

Or getting a little creative:

```
def hk[_[_]] = (); hk[({type \[X] = X}) # \ ]
def hk[_[_]] = (); hk[({type λ[α]=α})#λ ]
```

Comment: It's doing it as a type that I'm after (I'm aware of Scalaz's PartialApply traits) and Adriaan's mail makes it clear that it can't be done ... thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Can't find a way to do it as a `type`, but this works:

```
class HKId[A[_]] { 
  type Value[X] = A[X] 
}
```

This compiles:

```
scala> List(1): HKId[List]#Value[Int]
res2: List[Int] = List(1)
```

And this doesn't:

```
scala> List(1): HKId[List]#Value[Boolean]
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: Boolean
       List(1): HKId[List]#Value[Boolean]
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment on Jason's answer, I want to be able to do this as a type. So your answer that it can't be done that way is right too. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, on closer inspection, this is pretty much what I'd now call a correct answer ... the only difference between yours and mine is that I've substituted `type` for `class`.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala 3, `type HKId[A[_]] = A` is still not allowed but all the following type declarations work

```
type HKId[A[_]] = [X] =>> A[X]

type HKId = [A[_]] =>> [X] =>> A[X]

type HKId[A[_]] = A[*]  // scalacOptions += "-Ykind-projector"
```

[Polymorphic method works with type lambda, but not with type wildcard in Scala 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74267610/polymorphic-method-works-with-type-lambda-but-not-with-type-wildcard-in-scala-3)

Scala 3.2.2 ([scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/wl4ZBkDJSHGWKxDaRx6cuQ/1))

One more option is to make `Id` poly-kinded

```
type Id[A <: AnyKind] = A
```