# Polymorphic method works with type lambda, but not with type wildcard in Scala 3

Tags: scala, scala-3, higher-kinded-types, kind-projector

In Scala 3 I can define a functor for state using type lambda:

```
  given stateFunctor[S]: Functor[[A] =>> State[S, A]] with
    override def map[A, B](a: State[S, A])(fx: A => B): State[S, B] = State(a.run.andThen { case (s, a) => (s, fx(a)) })
```

I would expect it to work with `?` or `_` wildcard:

```
  given stateFunctor[S]: Functor[State[S, ?]] with
    override def map[A, B](a: State[S, A])(fx: A => B): State[S, B] = State(a.run.andThen { case (s, a) => (s, fx(a)) })
```

but I'm getting the following compilation error:

> Type argument domain.State[S, ? <: AnyKind] does not have the same kind as its bound [_$1]
> given stateFunctor[S]: Functor[State[S, ? <: AnyKind]] with

Why doesn't it work? What am I missing? I thought Scala 3 supports kind-projector syntax for type wildcards.

Scala version: 3.1.3

If you need it, here are `State` and `Functor` definitions:

```
case class State[S, A](run:S => (S, A)):
  def exec(s:S):S = run(s)._1
  def eval(s:S):A = run(s)._2
```

```
trait Functor[F[_]]:
  def map[A, B](a: F[A])(fx: A => B): F[B]
```

Comment: I believe you need a compiler flag.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez sorry, witch one are you referring to? I thought `-Ykind-projector` is used only when using kind-projector (so basically in Scala 2)

Comment: I've tried adding it using `Global / scalacOptions += "-Ykind-projector"` in build.sbt, but it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?` is wrong. `?` is for existential type `State[S, ?]` (in Scala 2 it was `State[S, _]` aka `State[S, A] forSome { type A }`), not for type lambda.

`_` is for type lambda (in Scala 2 they were emulated `({ type F[A] = State[S, A] })#F`). So it should be `State[S, _]` but this is not implemented yet.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/changed-features/wildcards.html

> The syntax of wildcard arguments in types has changed from `_` to `?`

> We would like to use the underscore syntax `_` to stand for an anonymous type parameter, aligning it with its meaning in value parameter lists. So, just as `f(_)` is a shorthand for the lambda `x => f(x)`, **in the future** `C[_]` will be a shorthand for the type lambda `[X] =>> C[X]`.

So far you can write `[A] =>> State[S, A]` or use [kind projector](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector) `State[S, *]`

```
scalaVersion := "3.2.1"

scalacOptions += "-Ykind-projector"
```

Comment: These next few years in Scala are going to be so ugly, when it comes to type projections. The transition plan for what `?`, `_`, and `*` mean in types is just plain confusing, and until all of the future changes have been implemented fully, it's going to be a mess.

Comment: Ahh, you're right! I've read that and missed the part that it's going to be implemented, I thought it's already available. Apparently I cannot read... Thank you, Dmytro!

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Not necessarily so big mess if people use Scalafix rules.