# Partially applied type constructor in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-3

Reading "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good" and trying to understand how Haskell concepts of the book may be written in Scala 3.

[chapter 11](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#:%7E:text=Another%20instance%20of%20Functor) mentions "partially applied type constructors" in section about Functions as Functors:

> Another instance of Functor that we've been dealing with all along but didn't know was a Functor is (->) r. You're probably slightly confused now, since what the heck does (->) r mean? The **function type r -> a can be rewritten as (->) r a, much like we can write 2 + 3 as (+) 2 3.** When we look at it as (->) r a, we can see (->) in a slightly different light, because we see that **it's just a type constructor** that takes two type parameters, just like Either. But remember, we said that **a type constructor has to take exactly one type parameter so that it can be made an instance of Functor**. That's why we can't make (->) an instance of Functor, but if **we partially apply it to (->) r**, it doesn't pose any problems. If the syntax allowed for type constructors to be partially applied with sections (like we can partially apply + by doing (2+), which is the same as (+) 2), **you could write (->) r as (r ->)**

```
instance Functor ((->) r) where  
    fmap f g = (\x -> f (g x))
```

I understand all this logic in the book + the fact that Haskell deals with type constructors just as with usual functions - those can be curried and partially applied.

**Question:**

What is Scala 3 analogue of such partially applied type constructor so we might define `fmap` in the way that visually resembles below Haskell definition?

(it is smth that can be modelled with higer-kinded types?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala 3 you can use [type lambdas](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/type-lambdas.html)

```
trait Functor[F[_]]:
  def map[A, B](f: A => B)(fa: F[A]): F[B]
```

```
given [R]: Functor[[X] =>> R => X] with
  override def map[A, B](f: A => B)(fa: R => A): R => B = fa andThen f
```

or [kind projector](https://github.com/typelevel/kind-projector) (`scalacOptions += "-Ykind-projector"`)

```
given [R]: Functor[R => *] with
  override def map[A, B](f: A => B)(fa: R => A): R => B = fa andThen f
```

Eventually this should become

```
given [R]: Functor[R => _] with
  override def map[A, B](f: A => B)(fa: R => A): R => B = fa andThen f
```

[Polymorphic method works with type lambda, but not with type wildcard in Scala 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74267610/polymorphic-method-works-with-type-lambda-but-not-with-type-wildcard-in-scala-3)

Comment: Dmytro, you rock 2nd day in a row  . type lambdas as type ctors - as key, cool. Also thanks for giving variants in your answers, very useful for learning